# Is there a relationship between the eigenvalues of convex combinations of two matrices and roots of convex combination of their polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $A_1, A_2 \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and denote $A := (1-\lambda)A_1 + \lambda A_2$ where $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Let $p_1(t) = \chi_{A_1}(t)$ and $p_2(t) = \chi_{A_2}(t)$ be the characteristic polynomials. Let us denote the convex combination of these two polynomials by $p(t) = (1-\lambda)p_1(t) + \lambda p_2(t)$. I am wondering whether there is some relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the roots of $p(t)$ (ideally some containment in either direction). Or they are completely unrelated?

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear relation and at least no inclusion. Take for example $A_1=\mu_1 Id$ and $A_2=\mu_2 Id$.

Then $p_1(t)=(X-\mu_1)^n$, $p_2(t)=(X-\mu_2)^n$ and $\xi_A(t)=(X-\mu)^n$ where $\mu=(1-\lambda) \mu_1 +\lambda \mu_2$.

But $p(t)=(1-\lambda) (X-\mu_1)^n+\lambda (X-\mu_2)^n$ and one can easily check that outside degenerate cases ($\lambda=0$ or $1$, $\mu_1=\mu_2$) $\mu$ is not a root of $p$.

---

Note that as your question can be seen as "is there a relation between the convex combination of roots and the roots of the convex convex combination" there seems to be results if you have additional assumptions (for example [if the roots are in the unit circle](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102779366)).